# Ways to manually commit offset in kafka consumers utilizing spring kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to figure out ways to manually commit offsets in Kafka consumer, using Spring-Kafka (1.1.0.RELEASE). I understand, that it will be better to commit these offsets for robust client side implementation, such that other consumers do not process duplicate events, that might have originally been processed by a now dead consumer, or because rebalancing was triggered.

I see there are two ways to handle this -

- Set the ACK_MODE to MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and in the listener implementation, invoke ack.acknowledge() API

  ```
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

  @KafkaListener(topics = "anotherBatchTopic", containerFactory = "batchContainerFactory")
  public void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<byte[], String>> batch, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {
      logger.info("===*** batch size : " + batch.size() + "***===");
      batch.forEach(System.out::println);
      acknowledgment.acknowledge();
  }
  ```
- Implement a ConsumerRebalanceListener.

  ```
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsRevoked(final Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(final Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {

  }
  });
  ```

However, with this approach, I don’t know how can I get a reference to the consumer, to invoke `consumer.commitSync()` or `consumer.commitASync()` APIs. For some technical restrictions, I cannot move to the latest version of spring-kafka that supports `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` and has a reference to the `Consumer`.

So what is the way to utilize `ConsumerRebalanceListener` to be able to commit offsets to Kafka ?

Also, I am starting multiple consumer listener threads using `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency()` API, so if specific consumer thread dies, does it have its own instance of the ConsumerRebalanceListener?

Comment: Try to avoid using internal Kafka commit. I would follow the option of having a external offset handling, it is safer. I use Zookeeper, for example. See more details in this Cloudera article: https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/

Answer (score 1):

The consumer rebalance listener cannot be used to commit offsets; with 1.x; the only way is via the `Acknowledgment` parameter.

1.1.0 is very old; all 1.x users are recommended to upgrade to at least 1.3.5; it has a much simpler threading model thanks to KIP-62 - see [the project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka).

The current version 2.1.6 (2.1.7 will be released today) has many more options, including `ConsumerAwareMessageListener` where you can get full access to the consumer.

You cannot interact directly with the consumer from the listener with versions < 1.3 because the consumer is not thread safe and the listener has to be invoked on a different thread.

Comment: How can it be achieved for Kafka 2xx?

Comment: See [the documentation for MANUAL_IMMEDIATE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#committing-offsets). If you still have questions, ask a new question with more details.

Comment: I have asked a new question with more details. Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730281/spring-kafka-manual-acknowledgement